# Replace all strings with loop - ANSIBLE

Tags: replace, ansible, ansible-module

I'm trying to change CISCOASA word here using the output I got. I've tried using lineinfile module in ansible but the replacement is not in order.

**ORIG JSON FILE:**

```
{    "servers": [
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": 22
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12346,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
}
]}
```

**REPLACE VALUES:**

```
CISCOASA1
CISCOASA2
CISCOASA3
CISCOASA4
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
{    "servers": [
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA4",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA3",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA2",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": 22
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA1",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12346,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
}
]}
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
{    "servers": [
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA1",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA2",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA3",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12345,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": 22
},
{
"ingress": "CISCOASA4",
"protocol": "tcp",
"source_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"source_port": 12346,
"dest_ip": "IPADDRESS",
"dest_port": "ssh"
}
]}
```

**Below is my task:**

```
   - name: Adding extracted ingress in file
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     lineinfile:
       path: /filepath/valid.json
       regexp: "CISCOASA" 
       line: "\"ingress\": \"{{ item[0] }}\","
       state: present
     with_items:
       - "{{ foo }}"
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the sequence of `{{ foo }}` ?

Comment: {
    "changed": false,
    "ansible_facts": {
        "foo": [
            [
                "% Network not in table"
            ],
            [
                "WAN"
            ],
            [
                "% Network not in table"
            ],
            [
                "WAN"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Answer (score 1):

this one do the trick :)

```
  - replace:
      path: ./file.json
      regexp: '^(.*?)CISCOASA\"(.*)'
      replace: '\1CISCOASA{{ servers_index + 1 }}\"\2'
    loop: "{{ vars_file_yml.servers }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: servers_index
    vars:
      vars_file_yml: "{{ lookup('file', './file.json') | from_json }}"
```

Comment: Hi I had to redo the task. But thanks for the loop_control it gave me an idea. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
   - name: Adding extracted ingress in file
     become: yes
     become_user: root
     replace:
       path: filepath/valid.json
       regexp: 'CISCOASA{{ servers_index + 1 }}'
       replace: "{{ item[0] }}"
     loop_control:
       index_var: servers_index
     with_items:
       - "{{ foo }}"
```

This answered my problem. :)